# Node.js http get web page not getting whole page

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, http, get

I am trying to pull a full html page in node.js from a network printer to scrape for ink levels. I have tried this:

```
http.get(options.url,function(res){
    res.on("data",function(chunk){
        data += chunk.toString();
        console.log(chunk);
    });
    res.on("end",function(){

        console.log(data);
    });
}
```

and this:

```
request(options, function(error, res, body){
    console.log(body)
}
```

Both return only part of the page. If I curl the same page from the command line, it will get the whole thing. There are no errors given by either function. I have tried it from multiple printers and each one returns the exact same amount.

Is there a limit that can be downloaded?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the actual printer data generated by JavaScript after the page loads or is the data in the HTML itself whenever you view the page's source?

Comment: The full data is there when I view the source. I can get the whole source if I use curl on the same machine, but will only get the first 1/4 of the page when using node.